# Google Earth Online - Places are not syncing with other devices

Tags: google-earth

I have been uploading KML and KMZ files via google drive to google earth online (I am using the project function).  I have been able to get it to work on my Mac.  Seems to be working great.

I have also pinned these projects so that they stay active.

However, when I click on "projects" on my phone or iPad nothing shows up.  I also have "sync" turned on.

Any ideas on how to fix this?